# Unsure of how to 'access' the HDD on my Razer Blade 15

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I recently purchased a Razer Blade 15 base model from Amazon (link [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HPQPNV1)). I'm decent with computers but one thing is stumping me. The laptop is advertised as 128 GB SSD and 1TB HDD. However, I can only seem to access the SSD and everything I download seems to be saving on the SSD. There's not much space on it and I imagine it's going to fill up quick. However in my file explorer, I only seem to see my SSD not my HDD. So in short I don't know how to 'access' my HDD so I can start saving things on it.

[image]

In the disk manager I can see the 1TB of HDD space.

[image]

I think conceptually I am not understanding something.

Comment: Did you format the hard drive from Disk Manager?  You need to do that.

Comment: It appears you have an offline unallocated HDD.  Why it's offline cannot be determined based off the information you provided

Comment: Its already formatted as basic simple volume, it needs a driver letter assigned to the large partition.

Comment: You should able to assign the drive letter in disk management. You may need to format it again, taking care to assign the drive letter.

Comment: The disk clearly indicates it's offline which isn't normal

Comment: Sorry how did you determine it was offline?

Comment: If you are sure the disk contains no data you want to keep, Read these instructions for initializing a disk. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/initialize-new-disks This is normal behavior for a disk that has been physically installed but never setup for use. Your TB HDD is the one labeled as Disk 0. Basically you just right click where it says Disk 0, and select Initialize. choose GPT when asked. Then add a new Simple volume to the disk, selecting NTFS when asked.

Comment: @FrankThomas that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @neerbasu - Based on the fact it doesn’t indicate its online?   The symbol also indicates its offline.  I have an HDD that isn’t allocated on my system and it specifically indicates its “online” similar to your other disk